# R e1071 SVM model twitter classification

Tags: r, svm

I have been using the e1071 library to classify text. I have been able to use the NB alogorithm but struggling to apply SVM. 
I have been following the guide from the [Cran website](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/e1071/vignettes/svmdoc.pdf)

The site has piece of code that doesn't explain the object Type and how I would get it for my own code.

```
> svm
> svm.model <- svm(Type ~ ., data = trainset, cost = 100, gamma = 1)
> svm.pred <- predict(svm.model, testset[,-10])
```

**My code:**

```
library(e1071)
library(dplyr)
library(caret)
library(rpart)



df<- read.csv("C:/Users/Suki/Projects/RProject/tweets.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


trainSVM <- apply(dtm.train.svm, 2, convert_count)
testSVM <- apply(dtm.test.svm, 2, convert_count)

svm.model <- svm(Type~., data = trainSVM, cost = 100, gamma = 1)
svm.pred <- predict(svm.model, testSVM)
```

I haven't been able to find an explanation but seen another similar example. Am I right in believing 'Type' is what I want the SVM model to predict? As what I have done so far I'm not sure how I would be able to give the SVM model that information.

Thanks for the time and help.

Comment: Yes, `Type` is what you are trying to predict. It should be a column in the data.frame that you are providing as the `data` argument. More specifically, `Type ~ .` is a formula that basically says "Predict values in column `Type`, using values in all other columns".

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried taken your advice by adding header = TRUE when I read the csv and then creating a variable df[,c(col1)] for the first column I want to use but I am still getting a error message. Could you further elaborate how I should make the column in the data.frame or do I need change the method I read the csv for the data,frame?

Comment: We don't have access to your data, so it's not possible to say what's going wrong. See my answer below for a demonstration with a built-in dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Type ~ .` is a formula that defines a model as "Values in column Type are dependent on values in all other columns". We don't have access to your data file, so let's consider the built-in dataset `iris`:

```
head( iris )   ## Look at the first few rows of the data
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
# ...
```

Suppose I want to predict the values in column `Species` based on values in all other columns. I can define the corresponding model as `Species ~ .`. Alternatively, if I only wanted to use some of the columns, I would put them on the right-hand side of `~`. For example, `Species ~ Sepal.Length + Petal.Length` would use `*Length` columns only.

Now that I have my dataset and my formula, I can train my SVM using the code you provided in the answer

```
myModel <- e1071::svm( Species ~ ., data = iris )
```

For demonstration purposes, we can apply the model back to the training data to retrieve predictions

```
predict( myModel, iris )
#           1          2          3          4          5          6          7
#      setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa
#           8          9         10         11         12         13         14
#      setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa
# ...
```

Finally, note that `svm` function has an alternative way to supply data / labels (take a look at `?e1071::svm`). The following is an equivalent way to train the model:

```
e1071::svm( iris[,1:4], iris[,5] )  # Predict Column 5 values from Column 1:4 values
```